# Linux loop script: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: apache, loops, memory, fork

I face a huge problem with a script on linux.
I work on an apache2 server and I have to execute a php script every seconds to update the database (yes, every second, I'm sure).
To do that, I created this script :

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ -f "MONFICHIER" ]
do
        php fichier.php >> log.txt
        sleep 1
done

exit 0
```

This script runs for a while and stops and I get this error message : "fork: Cannot allocate memory"

Actually everything works fine and after a while, a plenty of defunct processes are generated and it is because these processes that the memory is full.

About the php file it is a index.php file to the CodeIgniter Framework with parameters for the fonction to call. Finally it updates the database by checking data.

I'm sorry but I can't provide the source code (confidential) but the function is fast (less than a second)

Did any body have this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: The code inside *fichier.php* would be a plus, monsieur.

Answer (score 2):

Either your PHP script takes more than one second to execute and you have a lot of parallel php invocation, or it takes a lot of memory. Either way, nobody can help you with only the source of the shell script.

Comment: Actually everything works fine and after a while, a plenty of defunct processes are generated and it is because these processes that the memory is full.

Comment: Furthermore, the sleep command is not executed during the php command but after. I tried the script with a "echo" instead of the "php" command and the result was the same

Comment: I am not sure I understand. If you launch this script shell with only an echo in the loop, you get plenty of defunct processes ? This seems highly unlikely.

Comment: Exactly, I firstly thought this problem came from the php command and I tried to replace it by a echo in a file. But the result is the same.

Comment: Well, this is clearly not relevant anymore as a stackoverflow topic. Maybe server fault ? Anyway, it seems like something is wrong with your system, check your logs, dmesg, ...

Comment: I checked the logs and I have not found any error about my topic. Do you think a parameter in apache2 server configuration could stop a loop process? I am sorry if it is not revelant but I did not know how to call my problem ^^.

Comment: How exactly is you shell script executed?

Comment: Just with a "sh myscript" but I will put it in a service. My service will just launch the script on start.

Comment: I think the problem comes from the server because I tried to do a watch -n 1 echo "test" and I got exactly the same error message. Do you have any idea where this problem could come from?